# Expression Tree: TryGetValue of Dictionary

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a value from a dictionary this way:

```cs
Expression.Property(objParameter, "Item", Expression.Constant(key));
```

This throws an exception if `key` does not exists. How can I replace that line in order to make it safe?

Comment: if key != null then do something if this what you mean

Comment: `key` is not `null`: it's a value that does not exist in the dictionary. I am trying to find a way to check in advance for that.

Comment: Do you want to call the indexer (`[key]`) or the `TryGet`method ?

Comment: Probably I should be calling `TryGetValue`, but failed doing so with `Expression.Call(objectParameter, typeof(Dictionary<string, TColumn>).GetMethod("ContainsKey"), Expression.Constant(key)`

Comment: A dictionary is a  enumeration of KeyValuePair<key, value>

Comment: @jdweng, can you elaborate on your comment? I know that fact, don't know how to use it in this scenario.